# Understanding Memory management with NSDictionary release

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary

iOS memory management is still something weird to understand to me but that's the most interesting aspect to me also, so I'm asking for some help here with my code.

I try to instantiate a NSDictionary object, I use it then I'd like to release but I got an object released error, this is the code:

```
if ([jsonArray count] > 0) {        
    NSDictionary *commentDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < [jsonArray count]; i++) {
        commentDictionary = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"debugging message here"]);
        commentLabel.text = [commentDictionary objectForKey:@"commentText"];
        //[commentDictionary retain];
    }
    //[commentDictionary release];
    commentDictionary = nil;
    NSLog(@"NSDictionary retainCount = %d",[commentDictionary retainCount]);
}
```

Nothing special, I fill a dictionary from an array, in my code you can see I tried to release but than I commented out because of the error. 
Why I can't release the dictionary?

Besides what's the difference between setting NSDictionary to nil that returns zero in retainCount and release (that should make the count -1)?

I thank you very much in advance for any kind of help in this topic.

Fabrizio

Comment: Your code indicates a lack of understanding about pointer-based memory management.  Please read http://boredzo.org/pointers/ on what a pointer is and what it means for your code.

Answer (score 11):

## Do not call retainCount

`retainCount` is a horrible method to use for trying to figure out memory management.  The absolute retain count of an object is rarely interesting and often will be unfathomable due to implementation details.

[Read the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MemoryManagement.html).  It is pretty straightforward.

Now, to your code.

- the alloc/init assignment to `commentDictionary` in your first line isn't needed and that object will be leaked on the assignment that is the first line in the `for()` loop.
- instead of using for(;;), you could use `for(commentDictionary in jsonArray) {...}`
- there is no reason to retain or release `commentDictionary` in that code;  the object retrieved from the array will remain valid throughout the scope of that method.
- Objective-C is a "nil eats messages" language.  When you call a method on `nil`, that call will return 0 in almost all cases.

---

Oh, and what Cyril said.  The static analyzer is a wonderful tool!

Comment: @Fabrizio: One thing I think you've misunderstood is that you do not create variables with `alloc` and `init`. You create variables by declaring them; that's what `NSDictionary *commentDictionary[…];` does. You create *objects* with `alloc` and `init`, and every object you create, you must release (as stated in the doc @bbum linked to; read the whole thing). After you created a dictionary, you then replaced your pointer to it with a pointer to a different dictionary, returned by `objectAtIndex:`. Thus, you leak the dictionary you created, and your `release` goes to a dictionary you didn't.

Comment: bbum - Can you please update your answer to fix the "read the documentation" link? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

I advise you to run the static analyzer on that code: a lot of the mistakes that I do regarding memory management are explained by following the steps that the little blue arrows 
describe.

That's a very useful/cool/forgiving tool to discover your own mistakes and understand what's happening. Build and Analyze in the build menu.

PS: retainCount is often wrong;

Comment: You guys are all incredibile, this topic helped a lot, thanx so much. I've started to use the static analyzer today and it's just great. I also started to read about pointers and printed the apple documentation. So thanx Dave, BBum, Peter, and Cyril.